# Позиционирование дочерних блоков

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Возникла проблема в простой вещи.
Показывать нечего. В HTML есть 6 блоков, и надо чтобы когда у нас экран достигая определенной длины, в одном ряду осталось 4 блока, а пятый и шестой под вторым и третьим (то бишь по центру). Задать text-align:center` родителю не помогло. (display: flex использовать нельзя)

```
.dashboard{ //Родитель
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
.shorcut{
width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Если в первом ряду 4 блока, а во втором ряду блок под 3 блоком - то это никак не по центру, а в аккурат справа от центра

Comment: Да, вы совершенно правы, допустим 6 блоков, а 5 и 6 под 2 и 3

Comment: а почему флексы нельзя ?

Comment: ТЗ такое, что поделать

Answer (score 2):

Нужно задать блокам `display: inline-block;` В этом случае позиционирование через `text-align` будет работать.

```css
.dashboard{ //Родитель
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
font-size:0; //Убираем пробелы между блоками
}
.shortcut{
display: inline-block;
height: 100px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
outline: 1px solid #ccc;
width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard">
  <div class="shortcut"></div>
  <div class="shortcut"></div>
  <div class="shortcut"></div>
  <div class="shortcut"></div>
  <div class="shortcut"></div>
  <div class="shortcut"></div>
</div>
```